# x path is not working when taking the image of this website

Tags: python, path, scrapy

I am crawling this website

https://www.propsearch.ae/property/2528407

and i need to take the images on it, i do this:

> response.xpath(".//div[@class='fotorama__nav__shaft fotorama__grab']")

the x path is correct, but i am just getting empty result

I am using scrapy

Answer (score 1):

I guess some manipulation is done on the DOM after loading, this will give you the list of images

```
response.xpath(".//div[@class='dt-image-col']//img/@src")
```